# How to trigger css animation in styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, styled-components

Usually, we solve this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44846614/trigger-css-animations-in-javascript) by removing and adding a class with CSS animation attributes. How to remove animation attribute and add again quickly to trigger animation using styled-components library?

Answer (score 7):

You could use props to change the styles, for example:

```
const MyComp = styled.div`
  transition: width 2s;
  width: ${props => props.animate ? "20px" : "10px"};
`
```

You can then pass a prop when you use the component to trigger the animation:

```
<MyComp animate={booleanFlag} />
```

In this case, you can toggle the **animate** prop between true and false as necessary. Perhaps using state from the parent component.