# How to repeat fade-in effect on element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Update**

Adding a delay solved my problem:

`setTimeout(() => price.classList.add("fade-it"), 100);`

but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73778160/18431030) also worked for me

**Original question**

I have a fade-in effect on background color that should be repeated from time to time initiated by me.

I'm using pure CSS:

```
  <style>
    @-webkit-keyframes yellow-fade {
      from {
        background: #f96;
      }
      to {
        background: #fff;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes yellow-fade {
      from {
        background: #f96;
      }
      to {
        background: #fff;
      }
    }
    @keyframes yellow-fade {
      from {
        background: #f96;
      }
      to {
        background: #fff;
      }
    }
    .fade-it {
      -webkit-animation: yellow-fade 1s ease-in-out 0s;
      -moz-animation: yellow-fade 1s ease-in-out 0s;
      -o-animation: yellow-fade 1s ease-in-out 0s;
      animation: yellow-fade 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
  </style>
```

How do I restart this effect after it's already played once?

The code I have is not working after the first time:

```
    var price = document.getElementById("price");
    if (price.classList.contains("fade-it")) {
      price.classList.remove("fade-it");
    }
    price.classList.add("fade-it");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger CSS Animations in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44846614/trigger-css-animations-in-javascript)

Comment: One of the answers there is "The simplest method to trigger CSS animations is by adding or removing a class". That is what I'm trying to do but it doesn't work.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63561659/5625547) about a delay! `setTimeout(() => price.classList.add("fade-it"), 1);` should make it work!

Comment: Adding a delay solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @OceanOverflow I think `requestAnimationFrame` API is the better solution. Maybe give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by removing the node from the DOM then adding it back. The `append` function does exactly that, just append the element to it's `parentNode`. Give the element it's own wrapper to be the `parentNode` that way it will not be reordered with other sibling-elements.

```js
const price = document.getElementById("price");
const btn = document.getElementById("fade-price");
const fade = function() {
  if (price.classList.contains("fade-it")) {
    price.classList.remove("fade-it");
  }
  price.classList.add("fade-it");
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  fade()
});
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  price.parentElement.append(price)
});
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes yellow-fade {
  from {
    background: #f96;
  }
  to {
    background: #fff;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes yellow-fade {
  from {
    background: #f96;
  }
  to {
    background: #fff;
  }
}

@keyframes yellow-fade {
  from {
    background: #f96;
  }
  to {
    background: #fff;
  }
}

.fade-it {
  -webkit-animation: yellow-fade 1s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-animation: yellow-fade 1s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-animation: yellow-fade 1s ease-in-out 0s;
  animation: yellow-fade 1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4 id="price">$9.99</h4>
</div>
<button id="fade-price">
fade
</button>
```