# How to make an animation repeat after an element moves to another position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to make a box that moves every time its clicked, and stays there until its clicked again. I have an animation to make it look 'angry' when hovering over it, and an animation to run away once clicked.

However, I can't figure out how to repeat the animation after it moved. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44846614/trigger-css-animations-in-javascript) post that about adding and removing classes to trigger animations, but when I try to add and remove the classes a second time, its position resets and the hover animation doesn't replay.

I'm pretty new to HTML/CSS and JS, so I'm not sure its even possible with this approach.

HTML file:

`<button type="button" id= "box" class= "hovering" onclick="runAway()">DONT CLICK ME!</button>`

CSS file:

```
body{
background-color: slategrey;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

#box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 3px black;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;

  font-family:fantasy;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.hovering:hover{
  font-weight: bold;

  animation: angry;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;   
  animation-duration: .1s;
}

.hovering:active {
  box-shadow:
    inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6),
    inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.running{
  animation: runner;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;   
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes angry {
    
0% {transform: rotateZ(-3deg)}
50%{transform: rotateZ(3deg)}
100% {transform: rotateZ(-3deg)}
    
}

@keyframes runner {

  100% {transform: translateX(100%);}    

}
```

JS file:

```
function runAway() {

   let theButton = document.getElementById('box'); 

    theButton.classList.remove("hovering");
    
    theButton.classList.add("running"); 
    
    //how to repeat? simply adding and removing again doesnt work
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things you can try. For example cycling through different animations by applying different classes. Setting translate values directly using javascript and using `transition` rules to handle the animation.

Before we dive into that. I think it's good to revisit a couple of concepts that can help you build up these solutions

1. Only 1 set of CSS rules can be active on a given element.
   That means that if there's multiple `transform` rules on a single element, they don't 'stack'. only the rule with highest precedence is applied.
2. HTML elements are hierarchical, Child nodes in the tree are effected by their parent.
   This allows us to work around point 1. we can apply a `transform` on the parent  and a different `transform` on the child node.

## CSS animation cycle

The button has a `:hover` animation that applies a `transform`
When the `.running` class is applied, this transform is overwritten.
In our case, we probably want to keep the 'angry' behavior. while also moving the button.
I've added a wrapper/parent to separate the 'anry' css rules from the 'running' css rules. The parent will hold the running state. while the child holds the angry state.

for the animation; we simply cycle through different classes to apply a different animation on each click.

```js
function runAway() {
  let theButton = document.getElementById('run-away-wrapper');
  // cycle through the animations from 1 to 3, 
  // remove the class name it's currently in, add the new class 
  if (theButton.classList.contains('run-position-1')) {
    theButton.classList.remove("run-position-1");
    theButton.classList.add("run-position-2");
  } else if (theButton.classList.contains('run-position-2')) {
    theButton.classList.remove("run-position-2");
    theButton.classList.add("run-position-3");
  } else if (theButton.classList.contains('run-position-3')) {
    theButton.classList.remove("run-position-3");
    theButton.classList.add("run-position-1");
  } else {
    theButton.classList.add("run-position-1");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: slategrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#run-away-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
}

#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 3px black;
  font-family: fantasy;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.angry-on-hover:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  animation: angry;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: .1s;
}

.angry-on-hover:active {
  box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.run-position-1 {
  animation: runner-1 1s 1 forwards;
}

.run-position-2 {
  animation: runner-2 1s 1 forwards;
}

.run-position-3 {
  animation: runner-3 1s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes angry {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(-3deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateZ(3deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-3deg)
  }
}

@keyframes runner-1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes runner-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes runner-3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="run-away-wrapper">
  <button type="button" id="box" class="angry-on-hover" onclick="runAway()">
DONT CLICK ME!
</button>
</div>
```

Personally I think this hard to expand upon.

## Transition css rules

In css, the `transition` rule allows you to do something similar to animations.
You can define what rules should transition over a period of time.
If we apply that to a `translation` rule, you'll see that the box moves smoothly from one position to the other.
We can leverage this for the run-away mechanism.
Set `transition: transform 1s`, and every time the `transform` for that element changes, it will animation to the new position. we can change transform by applying a css class or by setting the value directly from javascript

```js
let currentX = 0;
let currentY = 0;
let negativeX = false;

function runAway() {
  let theButton = document.getElementById('run-away-wrapper');
  // toggle between positive and negative X values, this makes the box move a bit more 
  negativeX = !negativeX
  let optionalMinusSignX = negativeX ? '-' : ''
  let optionalMinusSignY = !!randomValueBetween(0, 1) ? '-' : ''

  currentX = randomValueBetween(90, 200)
  currentY = randomValueBetween(0, 100)

  theButton.style.transform = `translate(${optionalMinusSignX}${currentX}%, ${optionalMinusSignY}${currentY}%)`;
}

function randomValueBetween(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: slategrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#run-away-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 3px black;
  font-family: fantasy;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.angry-on-hover:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  animation: angry;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: .1s;
}

.angry-on-hover:active {
  box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

@keyframes angry {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(-3deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateZ(3deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-3deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="run-away-wrapper">
  <button type="button" id="box" class="angry-on-hover" onclick="runAway()">
DONT CLICK ME!
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I wasn't expecting such a helpful answer, thank you so much!