# Javascript cancel custom function and resume

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i cancel this function?  So the scroll event is canceled and i'd have to call the function again?

```
function scroll_play() {

    $('.media-tbl > tbody > tr').each(function(i, element) {

        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            /* checks if elements are in view */
        });

    });
}

scroll_play();
```

I specifically want to stop `$(window).bind('scroll',` , so i can do it at another time by calling the function `scroll_play()`

How do i solve this?

Comment: Use [.unbind](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) `$(window).unbind('scroll');`

Comment: .bind() is deprecated as of v3 https://api.jquery.com/bind/, use `on()` and `off()` https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler

Comment: So i can do `$(window).off('scroll');` and then call `$(window).bind('scroll', ` again?

Comment: @user892134 You absolutely *do not* want a scroll listener for every row in a table. That would cause performance problems

Comment: what happens if you bind the scroll event listener for too many elements can be seen [in this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56683298/animations-are-slowing-the-performance-of-web-page/56736244#56736244)  (hint, the answer was the same as it is now, use IO)

Answer (score 4):

You really should use [Intersection Observer (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this. This was developed to solve problems as yours, to handle elements scrolling into view (and also out of view)

First you set the options for your observer. For example, you can specify how much the element has to be visible when the callback function should fire:

```
var options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Here we say the element has to be 100% visible (threshold: 1.0) -> Then the callback is executed.

Then we define which elements to watch:

```
var target = document.querySelectorAll('.media-tbl > tbody > tr');
observer.observe(target);
```

and last we define what should happen when the defined element scrolls into view:

```
var callback = function(entries, observer) { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element:
  });
};
```

If you need to support older browsers, use [the official polyfill from w3c.](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill)

Comment: in `entries.foreach` try logging entry.intersectionratio, if this is small it means it leaves the screen, otherwise it is entering the screen. Also check [this example for checking if an element is 75% in view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Intersection_change_callbacks)

Answer (score -2):

Use

For jQuery > 1.7

```
$(window).off('scroll');
```

jQuery version <= 1.7

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

Comment: unbind is deprecated , use off()

Comment: From jquery v1.7 unbind() has been deprecated . If you are using jquery > 1.7 use off instead